# Mounted Docker Volume updating real time to changes in host machine

Tags: docker, watch, docker-volume, mounted-volumes

I have a dockerized application that grabs logs from a folder specified by the user's path in their host machine. The problem is that if another log is added in the folder, the application will not pick up that log unless the containers are restarted. I would like the application to automatically add new changes instead of requiring the containers to be reset.

docker-compose.yml file -

```
version: "3"
services:
  api-server:
    build: ./ExpressBackend
    volumes:
      - "(USER_PATH):/usr/src/app/watch-folder"
    image: express
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - react-express
```

Edit: I found that this is supposed to work, and works as expected on Linux when editing a file with the command line and not a GUI. However, the changes are not detected on windows when editing a file in the folder user path when using notepad.